# Problems while Populating a list

Tags: apex

I am trying to store two decimal values in the list as given in code below.
But , its always showing List inndex out of bound error  when I am trying to debug the list values.
Kindly assist.

```
  AggregateResult[] srtGrp  = [SELECT Survey_vod__c, SUM(Response_1_LBK__c) Res1, SUM(Response_2_LBK__c) Res2 FROM Survey_Target_vod__c  where Survey_vod__c  in : scope and Status_vod__c = 'Submitted_vod' GROUP BY Survey_vod__c];   
  for (Sobject sObj : srtGrp)
  {
     List <Decimal> reslst = new List <Decimal>();
     if (reslst == null ||  reslst.isEmpty()){
     system.debug('3c******************** inside list pop'+ reslst);
       reslst.set(0,sObj.get('Res1');
       reslst.set(1,sObj.get('Res2');
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "add" to add new items to a list. Using "set" replaces an existing index.